# Appium setup to run automated scripts (java) for iOS apps with .ipa file on mac

Tags: java, ios, macos, selenium, appium

I have a doubt, shall we test ios app with .ipa file on mac using appium with out building the app on xcode since its time taking process. Please help me here if we can test with .ipa file itself . Please mention steps if it is possible ....Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Appium doesn't care where the .ipa is built. It will function exactly the same as if you had built it locally. See [the standard documentation](http://appium.io/docs/en/about-appium/getting-started/index.html) for any how-to you're seeking.

Comment: Hi Mike Collins thanks for the documentation and i followed the same too. It installed app & webdriver agent but not launching the app its giving some error message , please have a look at the below error message                                                                                
                                                                                               
    [XCUITest] Unable to start WebDriverAgent session because of xcodebuild failure: "Could not proxy command to remote server. Original error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100"

Comment: Are you running on a physical device?

Comment: Reinstall all parts? Restart? Sorry, this is a tough one.

Comment: Ok , i will do that and let you know.

Comment: Its working fine now , i Reinstalled everything from the starting again. ...Thanks Mike collins